Python script for writing and reading sensor data via Modbus in combination with buttons (GUI Tkinter)
I am building such a program for the first time and therefore need help from experts.
I have created a simple GUI environment:
from time import strftime
from time import sleep
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from threading import Thread
import queue
import tk_tools

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure()

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 600, height = 500, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0, relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

canvas.create_text(380, 10, anchor = "nw", text = "Test", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter Bold", 16))
canvas.create_text(36, 69, anchor = "nw", text = "Article number:", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter SemiBold", 16))
canvas.create_text(36, 135, anchor = "nw", text = "Serial number:", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter SemiBold", 16))
canvas.create_text(160, 260, anchor = "nw", text = "Target:", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter SemiBold", 16))
canvas.create_text(280, 260, anchor = "nw", text = "Actual Value:", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter SemiBold", 16))

name = StringVar()
Article = Entry(textvariable=name, width=45)
Article.place(x=35,y=100)

name = StringVar()
Serial = Entry(textvariable=name, width=45)
Serial.place(x=35,y=165)

button_target_min = Button(window, text='0%')
button_target_min.pack()
button_target_min.place(x=55,y=380)
button_target_max = Button(window, text='100%')
button_target_max.pack()
button_target_max.place(x=55,y=310)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()

Now I'm about to integrate the logic but I'm reaching my limits. I would like the setpoint value of 4 mA to be written when I click on the 0% button. And 20 mA for the 100% button (of course, I call up the Modbus connection via ModbusClient). I wanted to do this with the following command:
Target_0 = client.write_single_register(0x801, 4)
Target_100 = client.write_single_register(0x801, 20)

How can I connect this to the button?
And then I want to look at the live values of the sensor and compare whether they match the target values. If these are not the same, then you have to turn an adjusting screw on the sensor until the target value is set. I'm trying to use a function, but I don't know how to build it in correctly. I need the live value of 0% and then the live value of 100%.
def Live_data():
    global Actual_Value
    Actual_Value = client.read_input_registers(9, 1)
    Actual_Value.set(Actual_Value)
    window.after(100, Live_data) 

But what is the best way to build this functionality? What could a procedure or a loop look like here?
I hope you can help me!
Thx!
Procedure to enable a sensor setting via a GUI.

You can assign a callback to the command option of Button and call what you want inside the callback:
...
def set_sensor(level):
    client.write_single_register(0x801, level)

button_target_min = Button(window, text="0%", command=lambda: set_sensor(4))
...
button_target_max = Button(window, text="100%", command=lambda: set_sensor(20))
...

For monitoring the actual level of the sensor, you need to create a text item in the canvas for showing the actual level, and update this text item inside live_data():
...

# text item for showing the retreived actual level of sensor
actual_level = canvas.create_text(280, 310, anchor = "nw", text = "", fill = "#000000", font = ("Inter SemiBold", 16))

def live_data():
    level = client.read_input_registers(9, 1)
    if level:
        canvas.itemconfig(actual_level, text=level[0])
    canvas.after(100, live_data)

# start the monitor actual level loop
live_data()
...


All I need now is the display of the setpoints. For example, the value 4 mA next to the 0% button and 20 mA next to the 100% button. Do I write this in the set_sensor function or outside like the other text fields? Thx

@Adalro You already know how to put text on the canvas, so I don't understand what you want.

Ok, sorry for the simple question.
